# Centering <a> button within a div

Tags: html, css

I can't seem to center my button in the middle of screen.

Here is the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/c7xuo1bv/

I'm not sure why the button is skewed to the left. I set margin left and right to auto. I think it might be a positioning issue but I tried position relative and absolute but to no avail.

HTML:

```
<header>
  <div class="background_image">
  </div>
  <div class="welcome-text-container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="welcome-text1">Welcome to Boothie!</div>
      <div class="welcome-text2">BE GOOFY, TAKE A PICTURE!</div>
      <div class="btn-row">
      <a href="#services" class="welcome-btn btn-lg">TELL ME MORE</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

CSS:

```
.welcome-text-container {
    /* z index --> stack order, higher == top of stack*/
    z-index: 100;
    /* relative position moes an element RELATIVE to its original position
        ie: behind the image!
    */
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 300px;
    padding-bottom: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.welcome-text1 {
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 40px;
}

.welcome-text2 {
    text-align: center;;
    font-size: 75px;
    font-weight: 800;
    color: #FFF;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
}

.welcome-btn {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #ecf9f8;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-left: 40px;
    padding-right: 40px;
    position: relative;
}

.btn-row {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    position: relative;
}

.row {
    padding-left: 50px;
    padding-right: 50px;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't help that the fiddle is empty either.

Comment: My mistake, sorry for the inconvenience. My mind was preoccupied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`text-align` style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align) affects an element's inline contents rather than the element itself.

You'll have to move the style to the parent `<div>`:

```
.btn-row {
    text-align: center;
    /* ... */
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/c7xuo1bv/1/

Answer (score 1):

you could add

```
.row {
    text-align: center;
}
```

to center all elements together.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/c7xuo1bv/3/)